# yepnope not working

Tags: jquery, yepnope

I have tried to implement yepnope, and no matter what I try, the yepnope events simply do not fire at all, no matter which example on their homepage I try. I have no errors in my Firebug log.

I have the following in my `<head>` tag.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="yepnope.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        yepnope({
            test: window.jQuery,
            nope: 'jquery.js',
            complete: function () {
                console.log('jQuery loaded!');
            }
        });               
    </script>
```

The 'jQuery loaded' message is never logged in the console. The jquery.js file is in the same folder as my index.html file, so this should work as is, right?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: Anybody with some information here, please?

Comment: Have you had a chance to test my code?

Comment: Hi @Joe thank you for answering. Nope - I had not had a chance; the notification from SE went into my junkmail folder. I will check sometime this weekend, and let you know what happens :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution - something I missed in the manual. I needed to have prop[er cache headers. Once I set the proper cache headers, it worked. This is on the YepNope homepage, under the heading "Things to keep in mind".

Comment: What kind of cache header did you use, can you show your code? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, Mark, it is long ago, and the code does not exist anymore. What I can tell you is as in my comment, under the heading "Things to keep in mind". I simply used theirs properly; I missed that initially.